# How to pass variable in PHP using include?

Tags: php, parameters

I have one page where i need to send some results to another PHP file.

include("test.php");

but i want to pass variable (var) also so that which can be processed by test.php using $_GET['var'] command. How is it possible in PHP?

Comment: retrieve your $var before including test.php, it will have access to everything declared before its inclusion.

Comment: It is possible by reading the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: I am new to php. Can u pls send me one example doing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$var1="hello";

include ("test.php");

the test file contains below code

echo $var1." world";